# How to avoid deletion of existing managed policy?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

Below is the policy rule to create once but cannot delete the policy once created through cloudFormation. These are managed policies.

```
      - Effect: Deny
        Action:
          - "iam:CreatePolicyVersion"
          - "iam:DeletePolicy"
          - "iam:DeletePolicyVersion"
          - "iam:SetDefaultPolicyVersion"
        Resource:
          - !Sub "arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:policy/some-permission-boundary"
          - !Sub "arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:policy/some-policy"


      - Effect: Deny
        Action:
          - "iam:DeleteRolePermissionsBoundary"
        Resource:
          - "*"
```

---

But through AWS console, I went and deleted those two policies directly, by selecting the policy, `Policy actions` ---> `delete`

Later I deleted the stack that created those two policies.

---

How to avoid deletion of policies? Why above rule did not avoid deletion of policy? given any `Principal`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Policies only impact principals to which they are attached.

Creation of a policy that denies (or allows) any action doesn't actually do anything to deny (or allow) that action, unless the policy is subsequently attached to a principal (IAM user, group, or role).

> You manage access in AWS by creating policies and attaching them to IAM identities (users, groups of users, or roles) or AWS resources. A policy is an object in AWS that, **when associated with an identity or resource**, defines their permissions. *(emphasis added)*
>
> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies.html

Since everything is initially denied by default, the fact that you cam delete the policy means your IAM user necessarily has been granted permission to delete the policy (more probably, you have permission to delete *any* policy) -- you already have a policy attached to your user that allows this.  The best way prevent an action is to not grant permission to perform the action.  You could also associate this policy with all users or a group of all users, then only the root user for your account could delete it -- but that's usually the wrong solution, because it's cancelling out a misconfiguration that granted the permission initially.

Comment: We want to assign this policy(as role) to aws EC2 instance, so that any user from that EC2 instance should not delete that policy.

Comment: If you have not granted the instance role any permission to delete the policy, then the role credentials already cannot be used to delete the policy.  But the instance role and attached policies have no impact on actions performed "from" an EC2 instance if the user supplies their own credentials and doesn't use the role credentials.  In this case, the problem remains that the user needs to have not been granted that permission.

Comment: Related question - https://stackoverflow.com/q/60272651/3317808