# Can IAM permission policy used to allow access to cross account resource?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

My understanding is,

*Service control policy* and *resource based policies* are mainly used to allow/deny cross account access to resources.

From the policy evaluation procedure explained [here](https://youtu.be/YQsK4MtsELU?t=876), I learned that IAM permission policy(managed or inline) is used to grant/deny permissions to `Principal` **within an AWS account**.

---

```
{
 "Version": "2012-10-17",
 "Statement": [

     {
         "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
         "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::*:role/Somerole",
         "Effect": "Allow"
     }
 ]
}
```

But above is the IAM permission policy, written to grant permissions to `Principal` in the source account, to have access(`sts::AssumeRole`) to other account resources(`Somerole`).

---

Can IAM permission policy be defined to allow `Principal` in source AWS account get permissions(`sts:AssumeRole`) to access resources(`Somerole`) that are present in other accounts(`*:role`)? In our case `Principal` is an **IAM role** in the source AWS account.

Comment: *"I learned that IAM permission policy (managed or inline) is used to grant/deny permissions to Principal within an AWS account."*  I'm not sure you can justify this assertion based on her presentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The other account would need to have granted access to the account. The role in the other account would need a trust relationship similar to this (often it has conditions added to it as well):

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::<AccountId_A>:root"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
```

This example assumes that  is the account you are granting the IAM permission in.

Comment: Yes, the role in the the target account has trusted relationship with role in the source account.. yes. **But**, by definition of *IAM persmission policy*, does it make sense to allow permissions to access resources across accounts?

Comment: It makes sense. S3 buckets, for example, are tied to an account once created. What if someone has a use case to access S3 bucket data from another account? They would need cross-account permissions to retrieve the data. This scenario is more common than you might imagine.